# Using an if statement to check if a div is empty

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove a specific div if a separate div is empty. Here's what I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ('#leftmenu:empty') {
        $('#menuTitleWrapper').remove();
        $('#middlemenu').css({ 'right': '0', 'position': 'absolute' });
        $('#PageContent').css({ 'top': '30px', 'position': 'relative' });
    }
});
```

I think this is close but I can't figure out how to write the code to test of #leftmenu is empty. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 303):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
if( $('#leftmenu').is(':empty') ) {
    // ...
```

Or you could just test the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property to see if one was found.

```
if( $('#leftmenu:empty').length ) {
    // ...
```

Keep in mind that *empty* means no white space either. If there's a chance that there will be white space, then you can use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) and check for the length of the content.

```
if( !$.trim( $('#leftmenu').html() ).length ) {
    // ...
```

Comment: `trim()` works perfect for me. Had to remove a column in Sharepoint that was adding some white space, in which `trim()` finds. Thanks.

Comment: As below, note you can use .text() if you don't want to count random invisible HTML as content.

Comment: @rogueleaderr Smart, didn't thought about using `.text()` because you could actually have some comment in the "empty" container and thus neither `trim` nor `:empty` would work. Thx

Comment: Would that be an efficient solution to use `.html()` If a container has a very long HTML content?

Answer (score 41):

It depends what you mean by empty.

To check if there is no text (this allows child elements that are empty themselves):

```
if ($('#leftmenu').text() == '')
```

To check if there are no child elements or text:

```
if ($('#leftmenu').contents().length == 0)
```

Or,

```
if ($('#leftmenu').html() == '')
```

Answer (score 23):

If you want a quick demo how you check for empty divs I'd suggest you to try this link:

http://html-tuts.com/check-if-html-element-is-empty-or-has-children-tags/

---

**Below you have some short examples:**

**Using CSS**

If your div is empty without anything even no white-space, you can use CSS:

```
.someDiv:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Unfortunately there is no CSS selector that selects the previous sibling element. There is only for the next sibling element: `x ~ y`

```
.someDiv:empty ~ .anotherDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

**Using jQuery**

Checking text length of element with text() function

```
if ( $('#leftmenu').text().length == 0 ) {
    // length of text is 0
}
```

Check if element has any children tags inside

```
if ( $('#leftmenu').children().length == 0 ) {
    // div has no other tags inside it
}
```

Check for empty elements if they have white-space

```
if ( $.trim( $('.someDiv').text() ).length == 0 ) {
    // white-space trimmed, div is empty
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can extend [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)
functionality like this :

Extend :

```
(function($){
    jQuery.fn.checkEmpty = function() {
       return !$.trim(this.html()).length;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Use :

```
<div id="selector"></div>

if($("#selector").checkEmpty()){
     console.log("Empty");
}else{
     console.log("Not Empty");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

also you can use this :

```
    if (! $('#leftmenu').children().length > 0 ) {
         // do something : e.x : remove a specific div
    }
```

I think it'll work for you !

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#leftmenu').html() === "") {
        $('#menuTitleWrapper').remove();
        $('#middlemenu').css({'right' : '0', 'position' : 'absolute'});
        $('#PageContent').css({'top' : '30px', 'position' : 'relative'});
    }
});
```

It's not the prettiest, but it should work. It checks whether the innerHTML (the contents of #leftmenu) is an empty string (i.e. there's nothing inside of it).

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this today and the accepted answers did not work for me. Here is how I did it.

```
if( $('#div-id *').length === 0 ) {
    // your code here...
}
```

My solution checks if there are any elements inside the div so it would still mark the div empty if there is only text inside it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had multiple elements to hide on document.ready. This is the function (filter) that worked for me so far:

```
$('[name="_invisibleIfEmpty"]').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).html()).length == 0;
}).hide();
```

or .remove() rather than .hide(), whatever you prefer.

FYI:
This, in particular, is the solution I am using to hide annoying empty table cells in SharePoint (in addition with this condition "|| $(this).children("menu").length".

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof($('#container .prateleira')[0]) === 'undefined') {
    $('#ctl00_Conteudo_ctrPaginaSistemaAreaWrapper').css('display','none');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if($('#leftmenu').val() == "") {
   // statement
}
```