# How to check if a div is empty after ajax load

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i am loading a php page in a div and want to check if the div has html content or not after load but every time it shows empty,used each method to check if it has html or not but didnt get any result.

Comment: fiddle? sample input/output?

Comment: you can use innerHTML() or jquery html() methods.

Comment: try to alert the ajax response to check whether some data is coming or not

Comment: used that to but it shows empty always although the page is loaded and php values are echoed

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if($('div.dataDiv').is(':empty'))
{
   alert('div empty');
}
```

Docs `is` http://api.jquery.com/is/

Possible duplicate of [Using an if statement to check if a div is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665466/using-an-if-statement-to-check-if-a-div-is-empty)

Comment: yes have tried it to but if it has content then also it shows empty.not getting why.

Answer (score 5):

you can check in jquery with various options like

To check if there is no text:

```
if ($('#headermenu').text() == '')
```

To check if there are no child elements or text:

```
if ($('#headermenu').contents().length == 0)
```

Or,

```
if ($('#headermenu').html() == '')
```

where #headermenu as your div ID.

Comment: yes and if it has content than also it shows empty can you correct me there

Answer (score 0):

Check for document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML.length()