# Change style of button element if text field is empty

Tags: css

I would like to change style of `#postBtn`, if `#textfield` is empty, something like

```
#postBtn:[#textfield.value.length==0]{
         border-color:gray;
         background-color:gray;
}
```

In html:

```
<input id='textfield'>
<input type="button"  Value="Post" onClick="post()" id="postBtn">
```

How do I achieve this without javascript?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your HTML markup? You may be able to use `:empty` but only if the markup allows for it...

Comment: @DrydenLong May you place sample code?

Comment: I can, once I see your HTML. Without seeing your HTML I could not produce an example that would do you any good.

Comment: @DrydenLong Edited, something else?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4665468/2040509

Comment: @MarioD I wouldn't prefer to use jQuery or javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you can add `required` to your input field like so:

```
<input id='textfield' required>
<input type="button"  Value="Post" onClick="post()" id="postBtn">
```

And then, using `:invalid` and the adjacent sibling selector (`+`), you can style the button if the field is empty like so:

```
#textfield:invalid + #postBtn {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/w7377/

**Note:** If the text input field is not actually a required field, then this solution is not the way to go. You may have to use a Javascript solution if that's the case.

Comment: @AlieN What `<p>`? I think that's another question since you don't any `<p>` elements in the code you posted...