# Change style of button element if <p> is empty

Tags: css

Since Dryden Long suggested me to ask another question, if I want to know, how to change style of button  if `<p>` tag is empty, I am asking.
 So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066720/change-style-of-button-element-if-text-field-is-empty) my question isn't duplicate.

---

I want to change the style of `#removeBtn` (using css), if this

```
<p id='text' required></p>
```

is empty, something like

```
#text:empty + #removeBtn{
  border-color:#ff0000;
  background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

My `#removeBtn`

```
<input type="button"  Value="Remove all" onClick="deletePosts()" id="removeBtn">
```

Comment: CSS is not aware of content. You need to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: @Diodeus What about `:empty`?

Comment: `required` is only valid for input elements. It will do nothing in this situation.

Comment: There is a :empty pseudo-class which means you can apply different styles to elements if they have no content

Comment: @DrydenLong Hello again, help me please!!

Comment: Where is #removeBtn in your html?

Comment: Your HTML is broken up in your post. How are the elements in relationship to each other? You should post the HTML starting with the `<p>` element, finishing with the `<button>` and everything in between.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id='text' class="btn" required></p>

.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  content: ".";
  display: table;
}
.btn:after {
  clear: both;
}
.btn {background:yellow;width:100px;color:red;}
.btn:empty {background:gray;color:blue;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

The only way for the CSS you have above to work is if the `button` is immediately following the `<p>` element. For example, your HTML would have to look like this:

```
<p id='text'></p>
<button id="removeBtn">Button</button>
```

But something like this will **not** work:

```
<div>
    <p id='text'></p>
</div>
<button id="removeBtn">Button</button>
```

This is because the `+` selector selects the *adjacent* sibling.

Comment: @AlieN Then there's no way to do this with just CSS. CSS only traverses down the elements, not up it. You'll have to either restructure your HTML or use a javascript solution.