# HTML -- Only show a div when it has text

Tags: css, html

Is there a CSS or pure HTML solution to having a div only be visible when it has content? I have this JSP code:

```
<div class="message-panel panel-alert">
  <span class="label-warning">
     <span class="warning-sign"></span>
  </span>
 <c:if test="${condition1}">
   <p> Condition 1 is true </p>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${condition2}">
    <p> Condition 2i s true </p>
 </c:if>
</div>
```

If either of the conditions are true, I do want to show the alert panel with my warning sign, but I don't want this div to appear at all if neither of them are true. Two solutions I can think of is to surround this whole thing with an all-inclusive if statement, or to modify the visible attribute of the div programatically in javascript. however, I am wondering if there is a way to say "Hey, div, go away if there's nothing in you".

Comment: JSP - Java Server Pages?

Comment: Just dont render the div if there is nothing to be put in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `:empty` pseudo-selector:

```
div.panel-alert:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a class called `hidden`. And add it to the `<div class="message-panel panel-alert">` when both texts are empty (using both ifs) and then in css define `.hidden {display:none;}` or as you stated use some javascript as described here [Using an if statement to check if a div is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665466/using-an-if-statement-to-check-if-a-div-is-empty)

Comment: He's trying to avoid having to do any checking in the server code that creates the page, and get CSS to hide the DIV automatically. Otherwise he can just use an `if` statement that skips the DIV entirely.

Comment: He wrote that he have both options available - one to put `if` around whole **div**, one to change css. I gave him something like merging the two options into one.

Comment: Read the question in the last line.