# Validate div is not empty with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate that both the text input, `.search-results` div within the "Current Images" fieldset and dropdown selection are all not empty. I have the logic for the text input and dropdown working, but can't figure out why the empty div logic is not working:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Asset ID" maxlength="64" class="form-control" id="imageid" name="imageid"> <span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default image-search" type="button">Search</button>
</span>
</div>
<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border">Current Images</legend>
    <div class="scheduler-broder">
        <div class="search-results"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Select Asset Type:</label>
    <select id='crop' class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <option value="default">Choose Type</option>
        <option value="now">Now</option>
        <option value="livefeeds">Live Feeds</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageid">Select an image</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-default form-control" id="file" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg" />
</div>


    function checkForInputs() {
    var filledUp = $("#imageid").val() != '' && $("#crop").val() != "default" && $(".search-results").val() != '';
    if (!filledUp) {
        $("#file").attr("disabled", true);
    } else if (filledUp) {
        $("#file").attr("disabled", false);
    }
    }
    $("#imageid").keyup(function () {
        checkForInputs();
    });
    $("#crop").change(function () {
        checkForInputs();
    });

    checkForInputs();
```

JSfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/L5adf7Lp/)

Comment: dirty, but `if($('search-results').toString().length === 15)` will be true if empty

Comment: You want to use this `$('search-results').is(':empty')`. Divs don't have "values" thats more for inputs, drop-downs, etc. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665466/using-an-if-statement-to-check-if-a-div-is-empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method ***.val()*** as it described on jquery website:

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

You should use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

In this case your validation should be

```
var filledUp = $("#imageid").val() != '' && $("#crop").val() != "default" && $(".search-results").text() != '';
```

So this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5adf7Lp/1/) is working

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Matt I'm really glad that I helped you

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(".search-results").text()` instead of `$(".search-results").val()`

Do the same for all the elements that don't belong to a form, like `div`, `span`, `p`, etc.

Take a look at the doc: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
if($('#mydiv').html().length() == 0)
{
  //do something
}
```

this is for compare with empty value

other way to do this task is compare with  function "children", example.

```
if($('.search-results').children.length == 0)
{
  //  dosomething
}
```

good luck !