# Remove class when no inner elements exist

Tags: jquery

I have the following class:

```
<div class='prod-item'>
</div>
```

I may have multiple versions of this class within the DOM. Is it possible to iterate through each, and remove those with no inner HTML elements?

For example, this can stay:

```
<div class='prod-item'>
<p>Pussy</p>
</div>
```

This should go:

```
<div class='prod-item'>
</div>
```

I have the following incomplete function, but I'm unsure on how to check if inner elements exist:

```
$('li[class="prod-item"]').each(function() {
    if(){
     this.removeAttribute('class');
   }
});
```

Comment: What did you try ?? i can think of 2 solutions in a minute :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an if statement to check if a div is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665466/using-an-if-statement-to-check-if-a-div-is-empty)

Comment: `removeAttrribute` will not remove the element, it will only remove it's class. Call `remove()` to remove the actual element. i have posted an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".prod-item").each(function() {
   if($(this).children().length == 0) {
     $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of fast variant:

```
   $('li[class="prod-item"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).children().length == 0){
         this.removeAttribute('class');
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the html() syntax:

```
$('li[class="prod-item"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).html().length === 0){
     this.removeAttribute('class');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter out all empty  div's using **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method and then remove `class` using **[`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)** method. The html content can get using **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method and check length of the string after removing trailing and leading spaces using **[`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** method.

```js
$('div.prod-item').filter(function() {
  return !$.trim($(this).html()).length;
}).removeClass('prod-item');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='prod-item'>
</div>
<div class='prod-item'>
  <p>Pussy</p>
</div>

<div class='prod-item'>
  <p>Wagon</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You used LI elements instead of divs...

```
$('.prod-item').each(function() {
   if ($.trim($(this).html())=='') $(this).removeClass('class'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

1) `empty` selector:

```
$('li[class="prod-item"]:empty').removeClass('prod-item');
```

2) or `not` with `has` selector here:

```
$('li[class="prod-item"]:not(:has(*))').removeClass('prod-item');
```