# How to remove a div if all inner elements have been removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which contains several li elements. Each li has a close icon. Once you click on it, the entire li item related to it is then removed.

However, once all li elements have been removed, then div still remains. In my project, it has a background-color so when li elements have been removed, then empty div area is visible.

I have tried all options on this link, but none of them worked. [Remove class when no inner elements exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855733/remove-class-when-no-inner-elements-exist)

HTML code:

```
<div class="divArea">
    <li class="li-item" id="li-item1">Item 1 <span class="icon icon-close 
item-close" id="item-close1"></span></li>
    <li class="li-item" id="li-item2">Item 2 <span class="icon icon-close 
item-close" id="item-close2"></span></li>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$( "#item-close1" ).click(function() {
    $("#li-item1").remove();
});
$( "#item-close2" ).click(function() {
    $("#li-item2").remove();
});
```

How can I make it that when the last li element has been removed, then div area will be removed as well?

Comment: just a side note but your html is invalid - li must be a child of ul or ol

Comment: so add a check to see if there are any elements in the parent, seems easy enough

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery

Answer (score 3):

Have a function that checks, which is called from each handler:

```
function removeAndRemoveParentIfEmpty(element) {
    var parent = element.parent();
    element.remove();
    if (!parent[0].firstElementChild) {
        parent.remove();
    }
}
```

each of you rhandlers would call it like this:

```
$( "#item-close1" ).click(function() {
    removeAndRemoveParentIfEmpty($("#li-item1"));
});
```

---

Side note: Rather than using `id`s, just use the structure of the list. Among other things, that means you can hook up a *single* handler (to the list) and then handle this in that single handler:

```
$(".divArea").on("click", ".item-close", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var li = $this.closest("li");
    var parent = li.parent();
    li.remove();
    if (!parent[0].firstElementChild) {
        parent.remove();
    }
});
```

---

Side note 2: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `li` as a direct child of `div`, it can only be the direct child of `ul` or `ol` (or `template`, but...). You'll need to fix that as well.

---

Live example fixing the markup and using the non-`id` event delegation solution:

```js
$(".divArea").on("click", ".item-close", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var li = $this.closest("li");
    var parent = li.parent();
    li.remove();
    if (!parent[0].firstElementChild) {
        parent.remove();
    }
});
```

```css
.divArea {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="divArea">
    <li class="li-item">Item 1 <span class="icon icon-close 
item-close">[x]</span></li>
    <li class="li-item">Item 2 <span class="icon icon-close 
item-close">[x]</span></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check that the item is the last:

```
$( "#item-close1" ).click(function() {
    if ($(".divArea > li").length === 1) {
      $("#li-item1").remove();
    } else {
      $(".divArea").remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#item-close1" ).click(function() {
    $("#li-item1").remove();
    // check if there are any other <li>'s
    if(!$(this).parent().find("li").length){
        // if not, remove the parent element
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

That said, your markup is semantically incorrect. All `<li>`'s *must* be a child of either a `<ul>` or an `<ol>` or a `<menu>`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an `li` as a child of a `div`. They need to be within a `ul`. This changes your logic slightly, as you need to determine if the `ul` is then empty when an `li` is removed, and if so, remove the parent `div`.

Secondly, don't use incremental `id` attributes. They end up making you repeat your code, or make it more convoluted. Use the common classes on the elements instead and traverse the DOM to find the related elements.

With regard to the actual issue, after removing an `li`, check the `length` of the `children()` of the `ul` and then remove the `div` if none remain. Try this:

```js
var $div = $('.divArea');
var $ul = $div.find('ul');

$(".item-close").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.li-item').remove();
  if ($ul.children().length === 0)
    $div.remove();
});
```

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divArea">
  <ul>
    <li class="li-item">
      Item 1
      <span class="icon icon-close item-close">X</span>
    </li>
    <li class="li-item">
      Item 2
      <span class="icon icon-close item-close">X</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that the `:empty` selector would be an alternative, but due to the textNodes between the element tags, resulting from the line breaks in your HTML, it won't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and this works Use a shape like this:  Note: I fixed your html to include the

```
<div class="divArea">
  <ul class="lis">
    <li class="li-item" id="li-item1">Item 1 <span class="icon icon-close item-close" id="item-close1"></span></li>
    <li class="li-item" id="li-item2">Item 2 <span class="icon icon-close item-close" id="item-close2"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
$( ".lis .li-item" ).on( "click", function() {
   var litm = $( this );
   litm.remove();
   var items = $(".lis").children().length;

  if (items == null || items <= 0) {
    $(".divArea").remove();
  }

});
```

Comment: Based on needs you could also use litm.parent().remove(); vs  $(".divArea").remove();

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure what situation are you facing, but here is some code fixing:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#item-close1" ).click(function() {
   $("#li-item1").remove();
  });
  $( "#item-close2" ).click(function() {
   $("#li-item2").remove();
  });  
  $(".divArea").each(function() {
     if($(this).children().length == 0) {
       $(this).remove();
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head

<body>

<div class="divArea">
    <li class="li-item" id="li-item1">Item 1 <span class="icon icon-close item-close" id="item-close1">X</span></li>
    <li class="li-item" id="li-item2">Item 2 <span class="icon icon-close item-close" id="item-close2">X</span></li>
</div>

</body>
```

Is this what you want?