# remove div if empty or appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need that when my div is empty, remove if not, run the appendChild code. I'm not getting the logic right, I think

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    if ('#leftmenu:empty') {
        $('#leftmenu:empty').remove();
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.iframe-output').appendChild(
        document.querySelector('.paddingbox iframe')
    }
});
```

Comment: `if ('#leftmenu:empty') ` should be `if (!$('#leftmenu:empty').length)` or `if ($('#leftmenu').is(':empty'))`

Comment: Thanks, dude! I'll try :)

Comment: Sorry was in a meeting so couldn't write a full answer - see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
        if ($('#leftmenu').html().length == 0) {
            $('#leftmenu').remove();
        } else {
            //do whatever

        }
    });
```

Comment: And how does your code work? What should the OP - or any future visitors - learn from this black-box of so-far unexplained code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want. Please refer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4665468/10687708) to find how to check div is empty. Then if not you can add the code you want. Currently, this code is the wrong syntax. You need to fix it like

```
document.querySelector('.iframe-output').appendChild(
document.querySelector('.paddingbox iframe'));
```

Comment: "*I don't know what you want.*" - so why write an answer? I realise you can't - *yet* - leave comments everywhere (but you're close), but why not wait until the question's had enough comments to lead to clarification and a clear explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( "p:empty" )
  //.text( "Was empty!" )
  //.css( "margin", "0" )
  .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Has text</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>Has text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#leftmenu').length==0) 
        {
            $('#leftmenu').remove();
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.iframe-output').appendChild(
            document.querySelector('.paddingbox iframe')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of errors with your code - you're if statement is only checking a string and not actually if the empty div exists and you have a syntax error on your append (and I'm not sure you can append directly to a collection like that)

Try this (comments to what I have changed)

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var $emptyDiv = $('#leftmenu:empty'); // get empty div

  if ($emptyDiv.length) {               // see if empty div exists
    $emptyDiv.remove();                 // remove empty div
  } else {
    $'.iframe-output').append($('.paddingbox iframe'));  // you may as well use jquery append as you are using jquery
  }
});
```

: